# Fill date in google form with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-forms

iam new in this field and I want to make bot using selenium to fill google form website using this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://forms.gle/VUwbshGuXxDb7NRbA")
time.sleep(1)
date= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")))
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{today_date}')", date)
next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mG61Hd > div.freebirdFormviewerViewFormCard.exportFormCard > div > div.freebirdFormviewerViewNavigationNavControls > div > div.freebirdFormviewerViewNavigationLeftButtons > div > span").click()
```

but i cant click next. Google form doesn't recognize the date

Comment: Did you try using the send_keys() function?

Comment: Yes and it wont send keys so i someone tell me to use this

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using actionchains, this is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://forms.gle/VUwbshGuXxDb7NRbA")
time.sleep(1)
date= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")))
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{today_date}')", date)
element =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Berikutnya']")

element.click()
time.sleep(1)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).send_keys("a").perform()
time.sleep(1)
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath to click on Next button.

```
//span[text()='Next']/..
```

**In code :**

```
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://forms.gle/VUwbshGuXxDb7NRbA")
time.sleep(1)
date= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")))
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{today_date}')", date)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']/.."))).click()
```

Comment: thank you but it still doesnt work

Comment: It did work on my local machine.. what's the error ?

Comment: google form still doesn't recognize the date. it's like the date still empty and need to be filled

Comment: @PasConnu :  That's an functional issue, nothing wrong with my code. When we are doing it manually, we are getting the same exception, don't we ?

Comment: as i said i know little to nothing about this thing so i just google and search and how it will work so now its already work, thank you so much for your help